Error MSB4018: "GetOutOfDateItems" task failed due to missing .tlog files on first build in Visual Studio
I'm working on a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 targeting Windows with vcpkg dependencies. I keep encountering an issue where the first build fails due to missing .tlog files, specifically a ParallelCustomBuild.read.1.tlog file. The error appears to prevent GetOutOfDateItems from running correctly, but on subsequent builds, the issue is resolved automatically. Here’s the error message I get:
error MSB4018: The "GetOutOfDateItems" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\project\something\projectname\projectname.dir\Debug\projectname.tlog\ParallelCustomBuild.read.1.tlog'.


Here are some additional details about my setup:

I'm using vcpkg for dependencies.
The project output is directed to C:\project\something\projectname.
I’ve attempted to delete .tlog files, but they seem to regenerate and cause the same issue.

Steps I’ve tried so far:

Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Deleting the projectname.dir\Debug directory and .tlog files manually.
Running Visual Studio as an administrator.
Disabling the "Use Fast Up-To-Date Check" option in project settings.
Changing the Intermediate and Output directories to a different path.

Despite these steps, I’m still encountering this issue on the first build after every clean. Has anyone experienced this before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

This issue is similar to this one, please check if your  path strings longer than MAX_PATH  chars and make sure you have sufficient permission to access the path.

I printed my character length it was well within the bound

Does Debug\projectname.tlog exist and is it a file or a directory?

It does not exisit

Could you please share a Reproduce example to help reproduce the issue?
